# How to implement Horizontal Icon list menu using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, mobile-application

Basically I want to implement something like below ,

- There is a menu button in the right up corner of the mobile.
  If user clicks that, horizontal bar **(like a google search bar in the android mobile)** opens in the left which contains the list of scrollable icons horizontally.

Is there any existing widget already present in Flutter ?
Kindly let me know how to develop this feature

Comment: Do you want the new bar to appear all over the AppBar, even over the menu button you already tapped? In that case, how will you hide this new bar again?

Comment: hello Pablo, in my case i do not have any app bar. just plain background with one menu button in the right top corner. so when the user clicks the menu button, the bar display on the left side in the same height of menu button

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of what I think you want to achieve:

```
bool showHorizontalBar = false;

Widget buildBarItem(IconData icon) {
  return Container(
    width: 100.0,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
    color: Colors.white,
    child: Icon(icon),
  );
}

Widget buildBar() {
  return SizedBox(
    height: 50.0,
    child: ListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        buildBarItem(Icons.directions_car),
        buildBarItem(Icons.directions_bike),
        buildBarItem(Icons.directions_bus),
        buildBarItem(Icons.directions_run),
        buildBarItem(Icons.directions_railway),
      ],
    ),
  );
}

Widget buildMenuIcon() {
  return IconButton(
    icon: Icon(showHorizontalBar ? Icons.close : Icons.menu),
    onPressed: () {
      setState(() {
        showHorizontalBar = !showHorizontalBar;
      });
    },
  );
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          showHorizontalBar ? buildBar() : SizedBox.shrink(),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: buildMenuIcon(),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `listview` to display icons horizontally

```
ListView(scrollDirection:Axis.horizontal,
children:[.. Icon(Icons.home).... ])
```

Comment: yes, I have to use the ListView with horizontal axis, but how can I fit this in to the Menu button. I have to show the bar after pressing the menu button. That bar should have the list of icons

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are trying to build here. You need a horizontal bar instead of a drawer, is that correct?